# How to generate NACA 5 digit airfoil coordinates?

Tags: airfoils

I want to generate NACA 63824 airfoil coordinates to use them in my bachelor thesis. 
I tried airfoil tools and java foil. But I can't generate 638xx series.

Can you recommend me a program or a code that generates these airfoil coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a MATLAB or Oculus user, there is the [NACA 5 digit Airfoil Generator](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23241-naca-5-digit-airfoil-generator/content/naca5gen.m)
program you can use. It works very well, considering it calculates the plot, as well as other main features of the airfoil, given the airfoil type.

Now, I am unaware of a program that gives plots based on the formula, but if you ever DO find out, please do not hesitate to post the link here.

Comment: I used the program but when I use the coordinates in soliworks to create the geometry of the airfoil. The surface appears very rough/zigzagged. But when I used airfoil coordinates from airfoiltool.com the surface was fine. Did u ever try using the coordianates to create a turbine etc.,?

Comment: Either use a much smaller increment or else fit a spline through the coordinates.

Comment: @MountainClimberi After getting the coordinates, I just need to multiply the x-coords with cord line and y coords with maximum thickness right ?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine. I've only used the program to get the points, and scaled the points after creating a model.

Answer (score 1):

NASA Technical Memorandum 4741 describes the calculations for Series 6 and 6A foils on page 8.

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19970008124.pdf

Comment: I asked for seires 5 and I know the formulas to calculate coordinates of the airfoils. I need a program that does that for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you know the algorithm, why don't you just code it yourself in your language of choice such as Python or Octave. If you don't know how to program, this is an excellent opportunity to learn. It's a skill you'll need.