# How to generate a NACA 6-Series Airfoil analytically?

Tags: aerodynamics, matlab

I asked this question over at [*Aviation.stackexchange*](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42509/how-to-draw-naca-6-series-airfoils) but after that I figured it might be better to place it here. Especially since there were really good answers on the [NACA 5-digit-Series](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13526/how-to-generate-naca-5-digit-airfoil-coordinates) airfoil generation.

I would like to calculate the profile NACA 64-2A015.
With the help of [*Aviation.stackexchange*](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42496/is-there-an-analytical-description-of-the-naca-642-015a-profile) I learned that the A-Version of the profile was created to ease manufacturing by thickening the trailing edge-section (by a straight contour from 80% chord backwards).

However, I am struggling to plot the profile based on the equations given [here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20050092351.pdf) and [here](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930090976.pdf).

[image: equations]

The implementation in MATLAB looks like this: 
Here is the Matlab code I used:

```
a = 0.4;
b = 1.0; % caution for NON-unity entries change the equation for h
% c = 1; to simplifiy the equation the chord is set to 1

cl = 1;

g = -1/(b-a) * (a^2 * (1/2  * log(a) -1/4) - b^2 * (1/2 * log(b) -1/4)); % g  = -1/(1-a) * (a^2 * (1/2 * log(a) -1/4) + 1/4)
h = 1/(1-a) * (1/2*(1-a)^2 * log(1-a) -1/4*(1-a)^2)+g; % simplified version for b = 1: h =  1/(b-a) * (1/2*(1-a)^2 * log(1-a) - 1/2 * (1-b)^2 * log(1-b) + 1/4*(1-b)^2 - 1/4*(1-a)^2) + g

x = (0:0.001:1);
y  = cl/(2*pi*(a+b)) * ( 1/(b-a) .* (1/2 * (a-x).^2 .* log(abs(a-x)) - 1/2 .* (b-x).^2 .* log(abs(b-x)) + 1/4 .* (b-x).^2 - 1/4 .* (a-x).^2) - x.*log(x) + g - h.*x); % y = cl/(2*pi*(a+1)) * ( 1/(1-a) .* (1/2 * (a-x).^2 .* log(abs(a-x)) - 1/2 .* (1-x).^2 .* log(abs(1-x)) + 1/4 .* (1-x).^2 + 1/4 .* (a-x).^2) - x.*log(x) + g - h.*x);

L6j01_x = [0, 0.005, 0.0075, 0.0125, 0.025, 0.05, 0.075, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1];
L6j01_y = [0, 0.01193, 0.01436, 0.01815, 0.02508, 0.03477, 0.04202, 0.04799, 0.05732, 0.06423, 0.06926, 0.0727, 0.07463, 0.07487, 0.07313, 0.06978, 0.06517, 0.05956, 0.05311, 0.046, 0.03847, 0.03084, 0.02321, 0.01558, 0.00795, 0.00032];

plot(x,y), axis equal, hold on
plot(L6j01_x, L6j01_y,'ro'), hold off
```

But the results do not match the data points from the Nasa-Reports
[image].

What did I miss to implement in the equation or is there another representation of the airfoil (excluding leading and trailing edge radius)?

Comment: Your expression for $h$ is not correct. $h = \frac{1}{b -a}$ ...

Comment: yeah kind of, it's because I set b=1 and then the log-term messes up matlab so I have two versions for it, that's also why I put the comment on b.

Comment: equation is to design mean line of naca 6 digit series airfoil, in the naca report it is shown that thickness distribution of this type airfoil section, what mentioned about is diffrent the equation

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I got this completely wrong!

The equation is not the profile contour but the chamber-line. Since a symmetric airfoil does not produce any lift, this ($y_c$) should be a straight line (which is exactly what happens for $c_{l}=0$).

The correct equation for the thickness distribution is a conformal mapping of a circle as described in [Nasa TM 4741](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19970008124.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a syntax error at the first term of y.

*Cli* is defined as the design coefficient of lift, not the *chord length*.

There can be other misinterpretations too. I'd suggest checking all terms once again.

Also, in the report it says that these equations are just a simplification of real coordinates of airfoils. (Just above equation 6). They probably did a curve matching, so even if all the equations are entered correctly, there will still be some error in comparison to a given set of coordinates.

Comment: I was not aware, that I mixed those up. I thought I have to put cl=cli to unity because I want an symmetrical airfoil.

Comment: Hm, now that I read it again, the chamber-line of a straight airfoil should be a line, right?

Comment: @rul30 , please try the corrected equation to compare the camberlines. Hope my answer helped you.